# Recycler View does not get generated on AVD

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

hope you guys are all well.

Newbie to Android development. I am trying out RecyclerViews but it is not getting rendered at all. Is there a certain step I am missing?

Here is my mainActivity kotlin file :

```
package com.example.alphablog

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.alphablog.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_main)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rv.adapter = PostAdapter()
    }
}
```

Here is my main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:i`enter code here`temCount="30"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my recycler view xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_business_24"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Title of Blog Post"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="285dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:text="Body of first blog post"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Edit and Delete action"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally, here is my adapter class boiler plate:

```
package com.example.alphablog

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class PostAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>() {

    class PostViewHolder(postView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(postView){

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder { // creates view to display
        val postView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post, parent,false)
        return PostViewHolder(postView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { // amount of items you will be working with in your recycler view
        return 30
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to charge the adapter with data.. and map those data to the `ViewHolder` views within `onBindViewHolder()` adapter callback

Comment: You don't necessarily need to, this code should still display 30 identical items. Have you checked the layout inspector?

Comment: @HenryTwist : Sorry I am new to Android Dev and haven't used the Layout Inspector yet. Will try to see if that brings anything.

Comment: @HenryTwist : I don't see any layouts popping up in the Component section of the Inspector which is weird...https://imgur.com/a/KsShvy2

Comment: I've just copied your code over and it works perfectly fine. Are you sure `MainActivity` is showing at all?

Comment: @HenryTwist : Ok phew, so it works on  your machine. So hopefully it some quirk that I am missing! I managed to inspect the Layout sorry still new to this : https://i.imgur.com/MxmRaUw.jpg

Comment: The layout inspector seems to show all the correct views, are you sure the text is set on `textView`, `textView2` etc...?

Comment: @HenryTwist : yup -> Here is an example : <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="285dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:text="Body of first blog post"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050" />

Comment: Do you think it's my AVD that's incompatible?

Comment: Seems unlikely that it has anything to do with it, but does it work for you on a physical device?

Comment: @HenryTwist : Thanks! I am not that far along in terms of deployment in my mobile learning. I will try and see if I can figure that out. Do you think I should create a new project and redo?

Comment: Well you should test it on a physical device first. Otherwise if your project is open source feel free to share it here and I can test it properly. Seems like we need to find the issue before starting a new project!

Comment: @HenryTwist : Thanks! The code I posted is all the code I have for my learning..unless you want my gradle code which is basic boiler plate. Would you mind running it on your device?

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, I've already run all your code and it works fine. Do you not have a phone to test it on yourself?